# Check for a user input in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a comment system that does not allow bad words to be inputted by a user. I have a database table that has 2 columns in it, one being the "bad word" and the second being the replacement word for the bad word. I use $_GET to get the user input, but I'm not sure how to check if the array has a bad word in it since each index of the $_GET array only has a letter. Is there a way to transform the array into a string so that I can just check if the string contains a word?

This is my php code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);
mysqli_query($link,"GRANT ALL ON comment_schema TO 'oviya'@'localhost'");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if(!empty($_GET["field1_name"])) {
    $field1_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET["field1_name"]);
```

does the mysqli_real_escape_string store the $_GET array as a string in $link? I'm not sure how that works exactly.I want to change the bad word that the user inputs into the replacement word before I insert into my database.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query and not manually escaping things. If you miss even one parameter you'll expose yourself to severe risk.

Comment: I think you need to replace the word from the database table right ?

Comment: Can you show me some input and your expected output so that we can help you

Comment: it's more of a general question I guess. What I'm having trouble on is that the $_GET call takes in a user input and at each index there's only one letter. I was just wondering if there is a way to convert each letter and make it into a string so that I can just compare strings?